# jQuery slider doesn't stop on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My jQuery slider is working but I don't know why it doesn't stop when I hover it.

I'm not using any slider plugin  for this.

Here is the code.

```
    $(function(){

    var width = 720;
    var animationSpeed = 1000;
    var pause = 3000;
    var currentSlide = 1;

    var $slider= $('#slider');
    var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
    var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');

    var interval;

    function startSlider(){
        setInterval(function(){

            $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function(){

                currentSlide++;
                if(currentSlide === $slides.length){
                currentSlide = 1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                }
            });

        }, pause);

    }

    function stopSlider(){

        clearInterval(interval);

    }



    $slider.on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);

    startSlider();
    stopSlider();


});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the last call to stopSlider(); should not be there. just kept it there in hopes of stoping the slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
var width = 720;
var animationSpeed = 1000;
var pause = 3000;
var currentSlide = 1;
var interval;

var $slider = "";
var $slideContainer = "";
var $slides = "";

function startSlider(){
  interval = setInterval(function(){
    $slideContainer.animate({
      'margin-left': '-=' + width
    },
    animationSpeed, function(){
      currentSlide++;
      if(currentSlide === $slides.length){
        currentSlide = 1;
        $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
      }
    });

  }, pause);
}

function stopSlider(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}

$(function(){
  $slider = $('#slider');
  $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
  $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');

  $slider.on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);
  startSlider();
});
```

Comment: i dont have the points to upvote an answer yet. it says i need to get to 15 reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to Stop the interval you need to do it like:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){//do stuff here});
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 1):

Man you do it wrong.
To stop an interval you need to assign it to a variable before.

1. Create your interval and assign it to var:

   var timer = setInterval(function (){
       // do stuff here
   });
2. You have your time setted up, now you can stop it! Like this:

   clearInterval(timer);
   Hope to help you :)

Comment: could you elaborate more or correct on the code and post. i have tried dont know if right but its not stopping still.

Comment: here is a link from youtube with same code but the slider is stopping. https://youtu.be/KkzVFB3Ba_o

Comment: error at the stopSlider function. timer not defined. still continues sliding.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove $ from your variable prefix, it is not php, it is jquery.